# Backing up Database in MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I created a Winforms in order to backup my Database. Then When I run my program it gives an Win32Exception was unhandled. "The system cannot find the file specified" Although the file is already existed and resulted to that exception.

Here is my code regarding my problem

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            path = @"D:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe -u " + txtBoxDBUsername.Text + @" -p " + txtBoxDBName.Text + @" > D:\C#\Client\Salesmate - EMC\SalesMate\Backup\" + maskeTxtBoxDBFile.Text + @"";
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            p.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use **MySqlBackup.NET** as alternative to **MySqlDump**
Documentation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256466/MySqlBackup-NET-MySQL-Backup-Solution-for-Csharp-V

 https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net

Sample codes:

**Backup a MySQL database**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

then the code,

```
private void Backup()
{
    string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                mb.ExportToFile(file);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Restore a MySQL database**

```
private void Restore()
{
    string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                mb.ImportFromFile(file);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I am one of the author of this library.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: By disclaimer, I mean about the fact that you are posting about your own product/website; what you added at the bottom in the 'Update'.

Comment: how can it be made to backup at regular intervals, say once everyday

Comment: @Smith Schedule task

Comment: If you have large database, mysqlcommand will give you timeout exception. You can increase it's timeout limit by MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

Comment: @HardikVinzava Yes, it is possible. But you have to modify all your tables to include "update_time". Then you have to cache the "last_backup_time" in a text file in your application folder. Then you will export all rows that have the "update_time" older than the "last_backup_time". Apply the option of `MySqlBackup.BackupInfo.ExportRowsMode = Replace`

Comment: Hi @mjb Thanks for your reply. Actually I don't have any control on adding new columns (as it's a third-party system) on the existing system. 
Do you have any other suggestions? Or Can we use this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.1/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html into your code?

Comment: @HardikVinzava I'm unsure how to do this at the momoent.

Comment: Why are you closing the connection manually? By using the "using statement" the connection is automatically closed.

Comment: Can you make a version of this library that doesn't use the Oracle GPL client?  As a result your library is also GPL!

Comment: @Abr I will try to have a look on this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to mention the user, pwd, db name and the target path..

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe -u " + txtBoxDBUsername.Text + @" -p " + txtBoxDBName.Text + @" > " + txtBoxDBName.Text + @".sql";
```

backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one.

```
public void BackUpData(string file)
{
    using MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = config };
    using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand { Connection = con };
    using MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup { Command = cmd };

    try
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        msgErr(ex.Message + " connection error.");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        mb.ExportToFile(file);
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        msgErr(ex.Message + " sql query error.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't putt the whole call inside "path = ", you should use "Arguments" to specify arguments, as name says. If library checks for presence of the called file (your whole path) it shouldn't find it!
- Are you sure that path is correct? You should find MySQL Server path using registry, not hard-coding the path, or if it can be not easy for you you can pass it as an argument from command line or specify from your form (settings page).
- You may have missed credentials: -u should be used for username (even if I use --user) and -p should be for password (even if I use --password). Why do you pass "txtBoxDB**Name**.Text" as password?!
- Maybe your destination path is invalid: it contains spaces, if you use spaces you should use quotes.
- What does txtBoxDBName.Text (?password?) contains? Spaces too? If yes it doesn't work.
- Last presence of  `+ @""` is completely useless, it doesn't insert any quotes.

A correct version of your code with quotes corrected is:
    
    `path = @"""D:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe"" -u " + txtBoxDBUsername.Text + @" -p " + txtBoxDBName.Text + @" > ""D:\C#\Client\Salesmate - EMC\SalesMate\Backup\" + maskeTxtBoxDBFile.Text + @"""";`

For more readability:
    
    `path = $@"""D:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe"" -u {txtBoxDBUsername.Text} -p {txtBoxDBName.Text} > ""D:\C#\Client\Salesmate - EMC\SalesMate\Backup{maskeTxtBoxDBFile.Text}""";`

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", "root", "password", "localhost", "your_dbname");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.StandardInput.Write(File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath));
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

This one worked for me you can try it out as long as you've your backed up .sql file

Comment: What is in output when take back up