# C# Application export MySQL database during running time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I built a windows form application using c# as a programming language and MySQL as DBMS, I want to add a button for exporting database when user click it.
What I created so far is :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM client INTO OUTFILE '"+path+"' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY'\\n' ", con);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
```

But the problem is that this code export data only NOT schema of tables. Is there is any way to export database with schema by **SQL statement**.

Comment: That sounds like a MySQL Dump. [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311492/backing-up-database-in-mysql-using-c-sharp) The first answer there uses the `MySqlBackup` object which should create a dump (DROP/CREATE statements and INSERT statements with the data as well).

Comment: I already check that question but it didn't work for me, do you think there is SQL statement to export schema with data as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MySqlBackup.NET**

https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net

Sample codes:

**Backup a MySQL database**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

then the code,

```
private void Backup()
{
    string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                mb.ExportToFile(file);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Restore a MySQL database**

```
private void Restore()
{
    string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                mb.ImportFromFile(file);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```